# Неправильный ответ при умножении матрицы на вектор Rust

Tags: матрицы, rust

**Есть код, который умножает матрицу на вектор:**

```
use nalgebra::*;

fn hesse() -> Matrix2<f32>{
    let m = Matrix2::new(6.0,0.6,0.6,6.0);
    m
}

fn main() {
    let hesse_inv = match hesse().try_inverse() {
        Some(inv) => inv,
        None => panic!("Can't inverse matrix"),
    };
    println!("{:#?}", hesse_inv);
    let mut q = DMatrix::from_element(2, 1, 1.0);
    q[(0, 0)] = 9.3;
    q[(1, 0)] = 3.9;
    let m = hesse_inv * q;
    println!("{:#?}", m);
}
```

**Выводится неправильное значение:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Правильный ответ:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]